Strapi export issues
I'm using this Strapi setup

strapi: v5.5.0
node: >=18.0.0 <=22.x.x
npm: >=6.0.0 database:
postgres

I’m attempting to do an export of my local Strapi instance. However, I only want to export a few entities, NOT all of them.
I’m following along with the Documentation here.
I’m attempting this in my terminal:
npm run strapi export -- --only content

And receiving these warnings before it wrongly exports ALL of the entities anyway:
npm warn invalid config only="content" set in command line options
npm warn invalid config Must be one of: null, prod, production

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a Strapi/NPM issue?
